# Is there a way to create with association in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I already know how create with one association but when i want to go deeper in the association i get an error.
[Sequelize documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ekcL.png)

Comment: Show an error message

Comment: i found the solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

for those who want the solution it's free

```
return Actor.create({
    id_actor: A,
    foo : [{
      FooA: A,
      bar : {
        id_bar: id_bar,
      }
    }]
  }, { 
    include: [{
      model: Foo,
      include: [{
        model: Bar,
      }]
    },
    ]
  })
```